# How to be notified of the Left of the telegram group?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I build `Bot` in `telegram`.
When the user is a `member` of the group. ,I `Save` record in database,(work by `notified` send to group)
and when member `Left` the group,I Will `Delete` this record,
But I `don't notify` in group.

How do i do it؟

Comment: What type of group? Large groups don't send those notifications.

Comment: this is super group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the **solution**.

`getChatMember` with parameters `chat_id`  `user_id`

it's return.
*Array ( [ok] => 1 [result] => Array ( [user] => Array ( [id] => 102281811 [first_name] => SM ) [status] => left ) )*

[status] is left/member

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned in a comment that you're testing with a Telegram supergroup.

Telegram doesn't send "member left chat" notifications in supergroups:

> Supergroups are muted by default and send fewer joined/left notifications.

-- https://telegram.org/blog/supergroups

Comment: I can see notified of joined member in supergroup. But left notify no show.

Comment: Correct. It's asymmetric like that.

Answer (score 1):

You should receive [Message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) updates including `left_chat_member` fields when user left, this is not in `text` field like normal message.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea to do it.

I call the `promoteChatMember` function. [by parameter `chat_id`,`user_id`]
and the other parameter by default value.
then this function return `result` `"ok"=true`.

I understand that it is in the group.

Hope to solve the solution.

Comment: I'll test it later.

Comment: I did not answer this solution.